# Override resource string in compiled assembly

Tags: .net, asp.net, resources

Is there any way for me to override the values that are stored in a third party assembly in an embedded resource file?

Using Red Gate's .Net reflector, I can see there are 6 resource items, but I only want to change to of them when using it in my web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to get the right resx file into the right place on the website. That did the trick

Comment: could you expand on this? I'm trying to do the same thing but I'm unclear with your answer.